# PHP link to page.php from another file

Tags: php, file, hyperlink

Im creating my first page in PHP with login form.
Here is my question,
I have this kind of structure:

```
MAINFILE:
 -index.php
 -asstes(file)
 -config(file)
 -includes(file) (with header.php)
 -user(file) with user.php
```

and after loggin from `index.php` i want to direct user to `user.php` but after using `header("Location: user/user.php");` i get `ERROR 404`.

Does anybody knows how to redirect to page in another file?

Thanks!

```
<?php

$error = "Email or password was incorrect<br>";

if(isset($_POST['login_button'])) {

    $login = $_POST['log_login']; //sanitize email

    $_SESSION['username'] = $login; //Store email into session variable 
    $password = md5($_POST['log_password']); //Get password

    $check_database_query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login='$login' AND password='$password'");
    $check_login_query = mysqli_num_rows($check_database_query);

    if($check_login_query == 1) {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($check_database_query);
        $username = $row['login'];
        $role =$row['role'];
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;


        
        if(role == "admin"){
            header("Location: admin.php");
          $_SESSION['role'] = true;
        }
        else {
            header("Location: /user/user.php");
            $_SESSION['role'] = false;
         
        }
           exit(0);
    }
    else {
        echo $error;
    }

    $_SESSION['log_login'] = "";
    $_SESSION['log_password'] = "";


}
```

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

Actually if in your index.php you have a login form which sends a POST request then, after a successful sign-in you can redirect user using:

```php
header('Location: /user.php');
exit(0);
```

Path passed in `location` is relative to user's current position so if your file `user.php` is in the root folder then use `/user.php`; if in `user` so that the filename is `user/user.php` then use:

```php
header('Location: /user/user.php'); 
exit(0);
```

Yet a lot of that may be caused by the way you actually sign in your user and how you manage the session creation so would be great and helpful if you have shared the code.

Comment: you have one typo there `if(role == "admin"){` missing `$` but this should actually not impact where user is redirected. Assuming that you have all the fields `login_button` `log_login` `log_password` user actually should get redirected. But are you sure that it happens after the mentioned line? Try placing `die("test");` after `header("Location: /user/user.php");` (if not using xdebug) and check if it will be hit; if so then it actually must be the missing file (maybe privileges?) or .htaccess configuration.